# How do I post data using $resource using angularjs

Tags: codeigniter, angularjs

I'm having a bit of a problem, I'm trying to do a http post request to my backend php. I'm new to angular and wanted to try the different REST method. I'm good with GET method. After this I will try UPDATE and DELETE method but for now I'm stuck on this. T__T.

Here a bit of the code in php

```
$data = array(
        "email" => $email,
        "password" => $this->input->post("password")
    );
$insert_data = $this->player_registration->insert($data);
```

And here my factory

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('webService', function($resource){
var apiUrl = "http:domain.com/feed/"; //change this to web service
var factory = {};

factory.registerPlayer = function() {
    return $resource( apiUrl + ':type', {type:'player'}, {
        post: {method:'POST', params: {}}
    });
};

factory.getPlayerByEmail = function () {
    return $resource( apiUrl + ':type', {type:'player'}, {
        get: {method: "GET", params: {}}
    });
};
return factory;
})
```

And my controller

```
function registerController($scope, webService) {
$scope.inputs = {};
$scope.inputs.email = "testuser@domain.com";
$scope.inputs.password = "password";

var req = new webService.registerPlayer($scope.inputs);
req.save()
```

My app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers'])
```

Comment: Why don't you just use HTTP post inside your service rather than using $resource?

Comment: Is it better to use $http compared to $resource?

Comment: Yes it is better using $http instead of $resource.

Comment: I ended up using $http. And got it all working ^__^

Comment: @WonderingCoder Can you post your working code?

Answer (score 0):

The default save() in $resources is actually `$save()`.

```
var req = new webService.registerPlayer($scope.inputs);
req.$save()
```

Comment: it gave me an error: TypeError: Object function c(c){t(c||{},this)} has no method '$save'

Comment: @WonderingCoder how is the factory declared? can you paste the full code?

Comment: @WonderingCoder I think you need to do `new webService.registerPlayer()($scope.inputs);`

Comment: i updated my question. Included most of the relevant codes. Could take a look at it.